# Android разметка. Тень View элеменов

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, разметка

Какими способами можно добавить тень view элементам в xml файле?

Comment: Не ленитесь искать на зарубежном stackoverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так -

```
android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"
```

или так -

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Если не помогло то читай тут - https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: Спасибо,
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
то, что мне нужно.
То, что указано в документации для моего API не подходит :/ (ну я так это понял)

Comment: Единственное, не знаю, как поменять цвет фона с белого, на тот, который мне нужен

Comment: Поссмотрите в документации,там должно быть